# how clear terminal completely after setting wsl2 as default terminal for Goland

Tags: go, windows-subsystem-for-linux, goland

I use wsl2 as Goland environment to run Go programs.

And I inputted some commands like `git status`,`git commit -am`,`git push`. So there were some lines in my terminal screen. Then I tried to clear them all by `clear`, `ctrl+L`, but they did not work as desired.

Here is a screenshot after using these commands.
[image]

How to solve it？ It is really bothering me because I have OCD and it gets me crazy!!!

I tried to search configurations in Goland settings, but the command `ctrl+L` it offered did not work well. Then I attempted to search on google. However I got nothing back.

Comment: What version of GoLand are you using? Can you share a screenshot after `clear` or `CTRL+L`?

Comment: That is the screenshot. I added it to the question content.

Comment: Do I get it right that after typing `clear` and pressing _Enter_ – nothing happens?

Comment: Almost. It just hides the lines. And you can simply scroll up to find that they are not eliminated.